# Clearfix problem, matching at the same line

Tags: html, css

Trying to float left and right at the same line, couldn't exactly make the clearfix properly.

the table is going down-side, with no problem but p-tag and the search-box don't match at the same line. It's basic thing actually, but help is needed. Sorry for the trouble.

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.row {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px;
    color: #395870;
}

.nav-p {
    float: left;
    color: #395870;
}

.search-box {
    float: right;

}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="row">
            <p class="nar-p"><i class="fa fa-building" style="font-size:24px"></i>販売概要</p>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <form action="{{ route('search.route')}}" method="any" role="search" class="search-box">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="search" placeholder="町, 地域, 会社名, 物件名" onfocus=" ">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="検索">
                    </form>
                </div>

            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">物件名</th>
                        <td>{{$estates->building_name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You declared `.nav-p`, but use `nar-p` in your code. Also, remove that single `<tr>`

Comment: what the :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change html code `nar-p` to `nav-p`

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.row {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px;
    color: #395870;
}

.nav-p {
    float: left;
    color: #395870;
}

.search-box {
    float: right;

}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="row">
            <p class="nav-p"><i class="fa fa-building" style="font-size:24px"></i>販売概要</p>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <form action="{{ route('search.route')}}" method="any" role="search" class="search-box">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="search" placeholder="町, 地域, 会社名, 物件名" onfocus=" ">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="検索">
                    </form>
                </div>

            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">物件名</th>
                        <td>{{$estates->building_name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```